# Does dolphindb support weighted least squares regression “wls”?

Tags: dolphindb

I have a request on weighted least squares. Does dolphindb support weighted least squares regression “wls”? How to use it?

Answer (score 0):

The usage of wls is shown as below:

```py
Y = [1, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3, 4]
X = table([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1] as col1, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] as col2)
w = wls(Y, X, 1..7, intercept=false, mode=0)
w
```

Result:

[image]